# How to concisely map through a list of lists?

Tags: common-lisp

I am looking for a concise way to map a variadic function across multiple lists, but instead of passing the lists as separate arguments as with MAPCAR, I want to pass a single list consisting of any number of lists, and map through those contained lists. I don't know beforehand how many lists are in the enclosing list, so I can't destructure it.

I've tried combining MAPCAR and APPLY in all sorts of ways, but can't figure it out. Must I give up on using MAP and just write the iteration explicitly?

Here's a function that does what I want:

```
(defun map-within (fn list-of-lists &optional(maptype #'mapcar))
  "Map FN on the lists contained in LIST-OF-LISTS"
  (cond ((null list-of-lists) nil)
    ((null (cdr list-of-lists)) (car list-of-lists))
    (t
     (funcall maptype fn
         (car list-of-lists)
         (map-within fn (cdr list-of-lists) maptype)))))
```

where

```
(map-within #'+ '((1 2 3) (10 20 30) (100 200 300))) => (111 222 333)
```

Is there some magical application of a lambda made from a map that could express this with just one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply` like this:

```
(apply #'mapcar #'+ '((1 2 3) (10 20 30) (100 200 300)))
=> (111 222 333)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a lot less magical than I expected, and obviously it hadn't occurred to me to just try it. I had the notion that APPLY took two arguments, a function and a list, and called the function on the elements of the list as args, when in fact it calls the function on the remaining args while treating the last one specially.

Comment: @PaulRichter: Yes, you should look at [`list*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm).

Comment: possibly works only for lists up to CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT, since the solution uses APPLY